# convert `void*` to `unsigned int` in constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

One cannot do a `reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(void*)` inside a constexpr, so I was trying something alike this;

```
constexpr bool is_null(void* ptr)
{
    return ptr == nullptr;
}

constexpr unsigned int get_id(void* ptr)
{
    return is_null(ptr) ? 0 : 1 + get_id(static_cast<char*>(ptr) - 1);
}
```

However I'm getting an error while compiling, about the ptr == nullptr not being constexpr, but only in the recursive call, not if I remove that.
So how, if possible, can I convert a `void*` to an `unsigned int` at compile time?

Comment: Why should `1 + function_which_returns_uint` have type `char*`?

Comment: Sweet, I got ICEs with GCC 4.6.3 and 4.8.1 with `template <void * P> struct Foo {}; Foo<static_cast<void *>(static_cast<char*>(nullptr) + 10)>`...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the expression with enough attention; still, I'm quite sure that this thing is going to blow up the compiler due to the mad recursion it requires.

Comment: Somehow I feel like it should be a defect in the language that the casts aren't constexprs. I wonder if that's already been filed.

Comment: Also, you are invoking undefined behavior (incrementing/decrementing a pointer outside array bounds is UB), and "an operation that would have undefined behavior" is not allowed in core constant expressions. (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1313)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Actually, if I'm reading this right it seems like it's quite purposeful: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1312.

Comment: @Matteo: Okay, I see that it is clealy invoking undefined behavior, but this doesn't answer the question, as to whether it can be done without triggering undefined behavior!

Comment: @Matteo: As for blowing up the compiler, then yea, this would never be practical, but I'm more interested in if its possible, than if its feasible.

Comment: If I had an answer to your question I would have posted it :-) . Still, the spirit of these restrictions seems to be that the pointers -> integers conversion is to be blocked at compile time. I think that the point is that generating a definite address at compile time is not always feasible (think about relocatable libraries, or to the required involvement of the linker), so getting the underlying value of a pointer is prohibited (in any other case the compiler can do the math with fake compile-time pointers, that only have to keep the correct differences between pointers in the same array).

Comment: Which compiler is that?

Comment: @Petr: Some unknown flavor of GCC provided with CCTools on Android.

Comment: Point is that the address of a variable is not yet computed during constexpr evaluation. At compile time that `ptr` contains the *name* of the object it points to, not the address, so it's impossible to get a "number" from that.

Comment: @Skeen I feel really stupid. Can you explain to me what's the problem? It seems to compile just fine:http://ideone.com/9K6HHv

Comment: @PetrBudnik This is arguably a g++ problem: The issue here is *not* that `constexpr` functions may not contain a `reinterpret_cast` (they **are** allowed to), but a `reinterpret_cast` makes the expression a non-constant expression. I.e. if you invoke that `constexpr` function in a context where a constant expression is required, the program is ill-formed. Note [dcl.constexpr]/5 says "For a constexpr function, if no function argument values exist such that the function invocation substitution would produce a constant expression, the program is ill-formed; **no diagnostic required.**"

Comment: @PetrBudnik See [the diagnosis of clang++3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9c82b7a8d16603c)

Comment: @sbabbi: I don't know if it's invalid, but one way to get the `constexpr void*`, is to cast the address of a function. I guess the compiler leaves it to the linker, to set the constexpr value in this case. See; http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/910c5edc32f73f10

Comment: @PetrBudnik@DyP: Clearly the program compiles just fine, if you do not enforce it to evaluate at compile time, however then there are a lot simpler ways to achieve the wanted behavier (namely just casting).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Can you tell me, if the program I wrote to sbabbi is invalid / invoking undefined behavier then?

Comment: @Skeen `(void*) some_function` is a `reinterpret_cast`, I just wonder why clang++ doesn't see that. (Try an explicit `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`, both are forbidden.) Besides, casting from one type to an unrelated type via two `static_cast`s invokes UB as well (AFAIK). Also, it's a known defect, see the already linked [DR1312](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1312)

Answer (score 1):

At compile-time address constant expressions are tracked by a "symbol + addend" representation, for example:

```
int x[5];

constexpr int* p = x + 3 - 1;
```

Assuming `int` is 4 bytes, `p` is symbol=x, addend=2*4=8 bytes.  p = x+8.

So you can only do pointer operations on address constant expressions that have the same symbol, because it isn't known during translation what their final relative address will be.  Further the addend may not go outside the object, mainly for safety, but also because you might end up at null.  For example suppose x was allocated at address 4000 decimal.  x-1000 would then be a null pointer expression, but that isn't known until link-time.

The rules in the standard are designed to support this representation.  The constant operations that can be performed on them reflect the information available under this representation.

Also note that the absolute address of variables of non-static storage duration isn't even known at link-time, automatic storage duration objects have a stack-relative address different with each function call, and dynamic storage duration objects have a heap address decided at run-time.